# Calculating returns with trading costs

Tags: python, finance, trading

This perhaps is an over simplification of calculating trading returns while including trading costs. I've made some assumptions - the commission for investing and extracting an investment is 1% and 2% respectively. The commissions do not change over the trading period which in this case is 5 time steps. I've used Python code to perform the calculations.

Set of positive and negative percentage changes in price for a given asset over 5 time steps is `{0.031% , 0.00121% , 0.0231% , -0.0213% , -0.0121%}`.

The commission to enter an investment is 1% of the invested amount, the commission to exit an investment is 2% of the current value of the invested amount.

**If I invest 1 euro in this asset, is the following correct?**

**1.**

The final investment amount if I do not trade the investment until $t=5$ is:
the final percentage change amount at $t=5$ which is `'initial invested amount' + '% change' - 'commission to enter' - 'commission to exit'`, therefore:

```
initial_investment_amt = 1

comission_in_amt = 1

comission_out_amt = 2

price_change = -.0121

return_amt = (initial_investment_amt + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100) = 0.97 which represents a loss of 1 - .97 = .03
```

**2.**

The final investment amount if I trade the investment at each time step until $t=5$ is:

```
initial_investment_amt = 1

comission_in_amt = 1

comission_out_amt = 2

price_change = .031

return_amt_1 = (initial_investment_amt + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = .00121

return_amt_2 = (return_amt_1 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = .0231

return_amt_3 = (return_amt_2 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = -.0213

return_amt_4 = (return_amt_3 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = -.0121

return_amt_5 = (return_amt_4 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

print(return_amt_1)
print(return_amt_2)
print(return_amt_3)
print(return_amt_4)
print(return_amt_5)
```

prints :

```
0.97031
0.9403220999999999
0.9105530999999999
0.8803400999999998
0.8502190999999998
```

which represents a loss of $1 - 0.85 = 0.15$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you seem to assume that at each time step you pay both an investment commission and a sales commission. Is that true, or is investment commission at the beginning for time step 1 and a sales commission at time step 5?

Comment: @JackFleeting In 1. I pay an investment commission at investing and when I take the investment out I pay a sales commission - so in this case two commissions over the series of 5 time steps. 

In 2. as I take the investment out at each time step and then reinvest it I have to pay an investing and sales commission at each time step. 

I hope this makes sense.
Depending on how the market moves during the 5 time steps each of these strategies will produce different returns as I've suggested in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to respectfully disagree with your conclusion for case 1:

> The final investment amount if I do not trade the investment until $t=5$ is: the final percentage change amount at $t=5$ which is 'initial invested amount' + '% change' - 'commission to enter' - 'commission to exit

The correct formula for the *final value,* I believe, is

> ((initial investment amount - commission to enter) * (1 + % change)) - commission-to-exit.
>   The main difference being the fact that the commission to enter/investment fee is taken out of circulation **before** the return on investment can be earned. This makes for a significant difference over time.

Assuming I'm correct, below is the code I propose. I took the liberty of changing some of the terminology for ease of reference, but you can obviously change it to whatever suits you:

```
p_changes = [0.03100, 0.00121, 0.02310, 0.02130, -0.01210]
initial_investment_amt = 100 #I used a larger initial investment; otherwise, the fees would have eaten you alive...
invest_fee = 1
sell_fee = 2

def periodic_ret(amount,change,reinv):

    if reinv == 0:
        if ind + 1 == 1: #for the initial period
            forward = (amount-invest_fee)*(1+change)      
        if ind +1 == len(p_changes): #for the final period
            forward = (amount*(1+change))-sell_fee
        else:
            forward = (amount*(1+change))
    else:
        forward = (amount-invest_fee)*(1+change)-sell_fee
    print(forward)
    return forward    

for i in range(len(p_changes)):
    reinv = 1 #1 if an invest and sell fee are paid each period, or 0, if an invest fee is paid once upfront and sell fee is paid once at the end
    if i == 0: #for the initial period
        cur = periodic_ret(initial_investment_amt, p_changes[0], reinv)
    else:
        cur = periodic_ret(cur,p_changes[i], reinv)
```

Output (w/ reinv = 1):

```
100.06899999999999
97.18887348999998
96.41083646761896
95.44308728437926
91.30032592823827
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the commissions and price changes are given as percentages. This means that immediately after investment the amount in the account is:

**initial_investment_amt*(1-commission_in_amt/100)**

The _amt suffix is perhaps confusing but commission is stated as % in the question.

After the first investment period the account has the amount:

**initial_investment_amt*(1-commission_in_amt/100)*(1-price_change/100)**

And finally after exit the client receives:

**initial_investment_amt*(1-commission_in_amt/100)*(1-price_change/100)*(1-commission_out_amt/100)**

I think the pattern is clear so you just insert more price_changes for a lengthier investment and if you disinvest and reinvest you'll have a lot more commission to pay. 
Hope this is OK - sorry no code - but it seems clearer like this and uses the question notation.